# How do I add jQuery that I can edit on my site?

Tags: php, jquery

I've tried using these two free web host sites; hourb.com 000webhost however I can't get my jQuery to work.

My file is called **myscript.js - JavaScript file**

On my pages I have added

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='myscript.js'></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing anything wrong? Do these free host not support jQuery?

Your help is much appreciated.

(If you wan't to look go here http://kennenmen.hj.cx/test.php or http://kennenmen.netai.net/test.php)

All I'm trying to do is get the images to play in a loop like a slideshow.

Comment: javascript works on client side, the host doesn't matter

Comment: You need to include jQuery before your script.

Comment: You have to include jQuery as well. Have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: so how do i get it to work on my site? ^ looking now

Comment: Wow feeling like a noob right now had the things around the wrong way tyvm :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='myscript.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

To

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='myscript.js'></script>
```

Order of inclusion is wrong. You can't access jQuery in a file loaded before jQuery is included.